# Extracting NSDictionary from a project

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `NSDictionary` in a project that was created over time and i need to take all the data from it from this project into another project.

Any idea how can i achive it without adding it one by one?

I thought about extracting everything into arrays and to pass arrays but its not really a good option

Comment: Stored data into keyChain and access it to another project.May be a good option for you.

Comment: .. Im not sure I understand. you want to share a NSDictionary between to apps at runtime or between to projects at compile time

Comment: simply wanted to take a nsdictionary and save its data in the app data so everyone who download it will have this nsdictionary inserted, like Maarten1909 suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probaly not the best solution but it will work fine.

You can convert the dictionary in to a string using the following steps.
Then you log the string and copy it. After that you can do a reverse of these steps in your new project.

**Project 1**

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary alloc]init];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSString *dictionaryString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",dictionaryString); #Copy this string from the debugger
```

**Project 2**

```
NSError *error;
NSString *dictionaryString = @"PASTE_DEBUGGER_STRING";
NSData *jsonData = [dictionaryString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: too fast perfect idea

Comment: thats a great idea but now i have a long string with tons of " marks in it, it will take years to change them all to \"

Comment: any idea what i can do with it?

Comment: so i used http://tools.zenverse.net/string-replacer/ with you solution and it works pretty good

Answer (score 0):

I would write it to a file and then import it in your new app. First you would ran the method in your app, and then take the file from the documents folder in iTunes. Add it to the documents folder in your new app and add the reading code.

**To save it:**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *stringsPlistPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDictionary.plist"];

BOOL success = [myDictionary writeToFile:stringsPlistPath atomically:YES];

if (success) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Your configuration file is in the Documents folder of the app which is accessible via iTunes." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
} else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"There was a problem creating the configuration file. Please try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

**To read it:**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *stringsPlistPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDictionary.plist"];

NSDictionary *loadedDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:stringsPlistPath];
```

This will leave your file there. If you wanted to delete it:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSError *error;
BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:stringsPlistPath error:&error];

if (success) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"The configuration file was successfully loaded and has now been removed." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"The configuration file was successfully loaded but could not be removed. You will need to remove it manually." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: is there a way to extracte the "myDictionary.plist" file into a new project? so even if i install the app on another phone the file will still be there

Comment: You could put the saved plist in the bundle and build it from there, then it would be with every release of the app

Comment: i saved the file but i cant find it anywhere in the project, sorry if i didnt understand you currectly

Comment: As stated earlier, you will need to enable documents sharing - in the info.plist set `Application supports iTunes file sharing` to `YES` - or use something to browse the iOS file system such as eExplorer.